# Modify part of an environment from a package: experimental environment of chemmacros

Tags: macros, environments, chemistry, chemmacros

General Question: How do I use an environment from a package and modify one or more commands but keep all the functionality of the the others?
Sorry if I should know that this isn't possible or viable and it's just easier to make the environments yourself from scratch (which would be beyond my skills).

Specific question: How do I use the experimental environment from chemmacros but modify for example the `\NMR`, `\pos` and maybe `\J` commands? And is it possible to still make `\\#{}` work with a renewed `\NMR` command?

For our reports we need to present NMR data like shown in the picture.

[image]

Renewing the `\NMR` command works well for use in the experimental environment and outside. But renewing the other commands doesn't work. And just `\newcommand` for example for `\J{}{}{}` works but only outside the environment.

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{scrartcl}
\usepackage{textgreek}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{chemmacros}
\chemsetup{modules={all},greek=textgreek}

\renewcommand{\NMR}[6]{\noindent\textbf{$\mathbf{^{#1}#2}$-NMR (#3)} (#4~MHz, #5~K, \ch{#6}, $\delta/\si{ppm}$):}   %\nmr{MZ}{Kern}{Nummer}{Frequenz}{Temperatur}{Lsm}
\renewcommand{\J}[3]{$^{{\textsl{##1}}}J_{\mathrm{##2}} = ##3~\mathrm{Hz}$} %\J{Bindungen}{koppelnde Kerne}{Frequenz}
\renewcommand{\pos}[1]{\textbf{##1}}    %Zuordnung

\begin{document}
\begin{experimental}
\NMR{1}{H}{prakt\_AC.999}{400}{298}{CDCl3} \val{1.11--2.22} (d, 4 H, \J{4}{HH}{6.66}, \pos{7})
\end{experimental}
\end{document}
```

And renewing the environment "deletes" all the other commands, like for example the `\val{}` command or the `\J` command.

```
\renewenvironment{experimental}{
\renewcommand{\NMR}[6]{\noindent\textbf{$\mathbf{^{##1}##2}$-NMR (##3)} (##4~MHz, ##5~K, \ch{##6}, $\delta/\si{ppm}$):} %\nmr{MZ}{Kern}{Nummer}{Frequenz}{Temperatur}{Lsm}
\renewcommand{\pos}[1]{\textbf{##1}}    %Zuordnung
\renewcommand{\#}[1]{\textbf{##1}}  %Anzahl Kerne
}{}
```

Comment: don't ask me why they want the assignment in bold, which is totally not the norm
and why they want numbers slanted for coupling bonds; they luckily didnt care for that yet so i just used the already provided \J(){} command with nonslanted numbers

Comment: Of course, you have to store the old definition of `experimental` first before if you still want to have its basic behaviour. And of course, the redefinitions are breaking the old style

Comment: For specific customizations of bold etc. output of the NMR etc. commands see section 7 of current `chemmacros`, p. 55 f.

Comment: »How do I use an environment from a package and modify one or more commands but keep all the functionality of the the others?« – an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/)! Your *real* question probably is »How do I change the layout of all the different parts from `chemmacros`' `experimental` environment?«

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The macros `\pos`, `\J`, and `\#` are set up through the `experimental` environment. They don't have a meaning outside -- at least not from `chemmacros`.  For each of them there exists an internal command which in case of `pos` can easily be redefined as the example below shows.

Here's a way to get the desired output (apart from the italic nuclei subscript – I suspect the example has this rather by chance than on purpose…)

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{scrartcl}
\usepackage{textgreek}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{chemmacros}

\chemsetup{
  modules = spectroscopy ,
  greek   = textgreek ,
}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\chemmacros_define_keys:nn {spectroscopy}
  { atom-number-space .skip_set:N = \l__chemmacros_nmr_space_skip }
\cs_set_protected:Npn \chemmacros_nmr_position:n #1
  { \textbf {#1} }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\chemsetup{
  spectroscopy/format = \bfseries ,
  spectroscopy/coupling-pos = sub ,
  spectroscopy/atom-number-space = 0pt
}

\begin{document}

\begin{experimental}
  \data{\NMR*{1,H} (ac\_prakt 12345)}
  (\SI{250}{\mega\hertz}, \SI{298}{\kelvin}, \ch{CDCl3}, $\delta$/ppm):
    \val{8.71} (d, \#{1}, \J(3;HH){4.4}, \pos{2})
    \val{7.66} (d, \#{1}, \J(3;HH){7.7}, \pos{4})
    \val{7.38} (dd, \#{1}, \J(3;HH){4.5}, \J(3;HH){7.8}, \pos{3})
    \val{3.03} (t, \#{2}, \J(3;HH){5.99}, \pos{8})
    \val{2.81} (t, \#{2}, \J(3;HH){5.98}, \pos{10})
    \val{2.2} (p, \#{2}, \J(3;HH){6.11}, \pos{9})
\end{experimental}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Tyvm! I hoped it's somehow possible with simple renewcommands...
However, when i copy+paste your code and compile it I get errors.

    Line 12: ! Undefined control sequence. \chemmacros_define_keys:nn
    Line 12: ! LaTeX Error: Missing \begin{document}.See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX Companion for explanation.Type H <return> for immediate help.... \chemmacros_define_keys:nn {s
    Line 12: ! Undefined control sequence. ...skip_set:N = \l__chemmacros_nmr_space_skip
    Line 22: ! LaTeX error: "kernel/key-unknown"!! The key 'chemmacros/spectroscopy/atom-number-space' is unknown ...

Comment: @Wulfram Then you probably have an outdated version and should update your TeX distribution…

Comment: true, after running the MikTeX updater it works; sorry for bothering with that

Comment: Where do I read about how to do those modifications that go beyond of what is in the documentation? (like here how to change the \pos{} command). All I did till now is using packages with the provided options and the occasional newcommands.

Comment: @Wulfram the option `atom-number-space` is documented but didn't work on my system – I need to check the sources. I am thinking of adding more options for customization. Regarding redefining code level macros – in an ideal world that wouldn't be necessary and at least for this question I'll add enough options.

Comment: I must remarked that when putting sth else in front like "\data{Smp.}: \SI{222}{\celsius}." then there is a blank line between this data and the NMR. How do I prevent that?

Comment: @Wulfram with `\begin{experimental}
  \data{Smp.}: \SI{222}{\celsius}
  \data{\NMR*{1,H} (ac\_prakt 12345)} ... \end{experimental}` there is no blank line?!

Comment: Sorry, ofc this is only with the option `list=true`. I guess it's becuase `\data{}` and `\NMR*{}` both add a linebreak? A workaround would be putting `\vspace{-\baselineskip}\data{\NMR*{}}...`.

Comment: @Wulfram I see… your guess is nearly right: with `list=true` both insert an `\item`. I'll edit my answer when I have time